# Adding a tooltip to text with a textblock

Tags: c#, windows-8, tooltip

I am trying to implement an app with a glossary which works in the following way.  The content is displayed in textblocks and in that content are words that I want to attach a tooltip to so when the user taps on them the definition is shown.  I'm not sure how to go about this as everything I've read so far has led me to think that tooltips can only be added to controls.  Is this right?

I've also been reading the guidelines about tooltips and I'm not sure if what I want to do fits within those guidelines.

I'd appreciate any advice about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think a tooltip would be a good solution for you in this case.
You should probably create an invisible Control inside your Template of each Item containing all the Information you want to show as your 'tooltip'.

Then you grab the Tap Event, or anything else, and toggle the visibility of the 'tooltip' control.

If you are OK with this solution I may give you some sample code when Im at home :)

Comment: And use something like a hyperlink to trigger each one?  This solution sounds like it may work for me. Thanks.

Comment: You wont come alone without work ;)
But if you use a Template for this it needs to be done only once...

Comment: Yes I was thinking of a template approach, they aren't always the best route though.

Comment: When binding to any kind of a Type T collection you try to use a template. Thats just whats XAML and MVVM about :)
OK I'll come back to you with an example later.

Please give me more Information about the Collection you are binding to!

Comment: I am using a collection which is very similar to the SampleDataSource file.

Answer (score 1):

While you are writing the contents in the text blocks. just note down the position of the texts which contains the definition.
Then, when the mouse pointer comes over the position, just display the definition in the tooltip using mouse hover event.

This is up to my knowledge...

Comment: MousePointer with a Multi-Device Application?!